# Is it possible to specify the `cls` argument of a classmethod, like it is with `self` for normal methods?

Tags: python

Is it possible to explicitly specify the `cls` argument of a classmethod?

E.g., this works fine, but `n` does not use `self` and therefore should be a classmethod:

```
class A():
    def n(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

A.n(self=B())
```

But the following does not work, while it seems equivalent to me:

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def n(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

A.n(cls=B)
```

The resulting exception is

```
TypeError: n() got multiple values for argument 'cls'
```

XY problem analysis: I have many class methods in `A` and many classes derived from `A`. This is essentially what I want to do:

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def n1(cls): print("1", cls.__name__)
    @classmethod
    def n2(cls): print("2", cls.__name__)
    @classmethod
    def n3(cls): print("3", cls.__name__)

class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(A): pass
class E(A): pass
class F(A): pass

for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for fun in [A.n1, A.n2, A.n3]:
        fun(cls)
```

It works when the last line is replaced with

```
        getattr(cls, fun.__name__)()
```

but I find this rather ugly.

I'm expecting the answer to the title question is 'no', so my followup (and perhaps actual) question is 'why?'. I'm confused why `fun(cls)` is not allowed. Perhaps `@classmethod` is just doing a `functools.partial`?

(Arguably I'm doing something unconventional in my design, because I also would like these methods be a `@classmethod` and a `@property` at the same time which is not possible.)

Comment: Just use `@staticmethod` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that class methods are actual *methods* on the class itself. An instance method, accessed through the class, is just a function (at least on Python 3, which removed the concept of unbound methods); it's only a bound method when accessed on an instance. But when you do `A.n`, it's making a bound class method; the `cls` is embedded in it, so you can't pass it again. This is because of how the descriptor protocol is implemented on each; a `classmethod` binds (to the class) whether it's accessed on a class or instance, an instance method only when accessed on an instance, returning the original function when accessed from the class, and a `staticmethod` never binds (always returns the original function).

You have a few options:

1. Use it as a proper class method; just call `B.n()`. This is what you should be doing 99% of the time.
2. If it's never used as a classmethod (never passes `cls` implicitly, always as an explicit argument), make it an `@staticmethod` that still takes `cls`, which means it never binds, you *must* pass a `cls` argument each time
3. Undo the effect of method binding by manually unwrapping the bound class method (a little ugly, but possible if you must support both implicit and explicit passing of the class): `A.n.__func__(B)`

**Option #3 gives the minimal fix for your use case**:

```
for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for method in [A.n1, A.n2, A.n3]:
        method.__func__(cls)
```

Alternatively, you can make it less ugly by just using the name itself; you don't need to access anything on `A` anyway, so just do:

```
for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for fun in ['n1', 'n2', 'n3']:
        getattr(cls, fun)()
```

or for slightly greater efficiency and slightly cleaner code, make an accessor function ahead of time and use it:

```
from operator import attrgetter

funcgetter = attrgetter('n1', 'n2', 'n3')
for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for fun in funcgetter(cls):
        fun()
```

A similar trick could be done with `methodcaller` to reduce the verbosity of `getattr` calls at point of use, but in this case I think the `attrgetter` is a little cleaner:

```
from operator import methodcaller

funccallers = methodcaller('n1'), methodcaller('n2'), methodcaller('n3')
for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for caller in funccallers:
        caller(cls)
```

Comment: "methods are bound functions" click! I'll use solution 1 and 3. I'd prefer `__func__` over explicitly giving the names because that feels like 'using data as code'. And `attrgetter` and `methodcaller` are also new to me, thanks.

Comment: @BlackShift: Note that there is a reason to prefer #1, or one of the name-based lookup approaches (`getattr`, `attrgetter` or `methodcaller`), over #2 or #3. A real "class method" should always assume it might not merely be *called* on subclass, but *overridden* as well. By explicitly using `A`'s version of the class method, you prevent `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. from providing their own implementations. If `A`'s version is logically the only version, and should always be called through `A`, you may as well make it a `staticmethod` and pass the relevant class manually all the time.

Comment: You are right @ShadowRanger. These methods are indeed overridden. I'll just write them out (#1) instead of the double for loop. "Explicit is better than implicit", and there are only a few relevant methods (known in advance) so it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can encapsulate the ugliness within `A`:

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def n1(cls): print("1", cls.__name__)
    @classmethod
    def n2(cls): print("2", cls.__name__)
    @classmethod
    def n3(cls): print("3", cls.__name__)

    @staticmethod
    def call_method(cls, fun):
        getattr(cls, fun.__name__)()

class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(A): pass
class E(A): pass
class F(A): pass

for cls in [B, C, D, E, F]:
    for fun in [A.n1, A.n2, A.n3]:
        A.call_method(cls, fun)
```